# Removed permissions still listed in Google Play listing (app in early access)

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I'm about to launch an app on Google Play. The initial alpha versions of the app required basically *all* permissions (camera etc.) by mistake. I've fixed this, and the app no longer requires any of those things, *but* the Google Play listing (available to those in the closed beta) still lists all of them. I noticed a message above saying:

> Showing permissions for all versions of this app

So I guess the reason that all of these permissions are still listed is because the previous version asked for them. I guess that's reasonable in a way because users may still have an old version of the app.

My question is: Will this remain when I leave closed beta and go to production and launch it publicly on Play Store, or will I have to restart the whole play store app process and make a brand new app to get rid of it? To be clear, the latest version *does not* use those permissions, and the old beta versions will never be used again.

**Screenshot from Play Store:**

[image]

Comment: You need to create an empty closed alpha and beta release to override this behavior. So the permission won't brought to the production release. I've experienced the same problem with my previous project. Afaik, it's a bug in google play console.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was caused by an old internal testing track build that was still available (for internal testers). Making a new release on that track with the latest version fixed it.